# Different connector options for 5A

Tags: connector

I am working on a submersible ROV robot with 20 meter tether. The ROV will have 3 motors and a camera and the electronics part will be encased in an ABS case with a monitor and powered through a 12V car battery.

I am working on the electronics part at the moment. The case should ideally have a panel mount connector at the back of the case (either circular or any shape; doesn't matter) maybe 10-pin and the contacts should be able to provide at least 5A of current.

The tether on the other hand, should be a connector that would mate with the connector at the back of the case which can be detached if need be, and should be fastened with a screw or something so that the connector does not come off if the tether cable is pulled. I have been trying to look for a supplier like Digikey or Mouser that can provide this kind of connector. I would need to buy around 50 pairs for all my students so they need to have enough stock.

Comment: Have you figured the voltage drop on 20m of wire round trip at 12 volts? You might need some big wire...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine, Sure, I intend to use 18 AWG wire. I have tested it and the drop is about 0.6V-0.8V

Comment: Does this connector need to be sealed? If so, to what depth of water? Do the IP ratings cover this depth?  If IP67 was adequate then you can use this as part of the search criteria.

Comment: @Kartman, doesn't need to be water sealed as it will be on the case safely ashore.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to combine the "electrical cable" and "physical tether" into one component, and thus combine "electrical connector" and "physical attachment".   There are a few in the "military grade" category like Amphenol MS, but I wouldn't want to pay for fifty of them.

Instead of looking for a unicorn product, I would separate the jobs.  Use an appropriate cable connector for the quick disconnect.  Then, route the cable through some sort of physical cleat/saddle to provide strain relief to the cable.   Maybe a handy storage hook that provides a way to capture the cable.

Don't underestimate the importance of voltage drop on a long distance low voltage cable. This is the undoing of many low-voltage projects.  For 0.7V drop at 5 amps at 20m, math says 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum wire.  Aluminum could be a good fit for underwater, since it weighs less per volume, so is closer to neutral buoyancy (insulation included).